# 'http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer' claim is missing error in Sitecore 9.1

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication

When trying to login Sitecore 9.1 CMS server with Azure Ad fedAuth, I am not getting loggedin. When I checked the Sitecore logs it shows the below error,

```
ERROR [Sitecore Identity] Unable to get user info - Internal Server Error
ERROR [Sitecore Identity] 'http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer' claim is missing
ERROR Unable to create a user. Reason: DuplicateUserName
```

When I checked the identityserver in the meantime, i am getting the below error,

> ```
> {
>   \"ClientId\": \"Sitecore\",
>   \"ClientName\": \"Sitecore\",
>   \"RedirectUri\": \"https://<url>/identity/signin\",
>   \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
>     \"{AllowedCorsOrigin}/identity/signin\",
>     \"{AllowedCorsOrigin}/signin-oidc\"
>   ],
>   \"SubjectId\": \"ecY44O9pG4FUjQS7HqIgI8LWetZHHnrJn2u83KwtSsg\",
>   \"ResponseType\": \"code id_token token\",
>   \"ResponseMode\": \"form_post\",
>   \"GrantType\": \"hybrid\",
>   \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid sitecore.profile\",
>   \"State\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=zYO-qtV_MLTRvsaL8md9EXlT0L0-ljoenKICj2aJYW2fXwvg4bms9-Fa9JlNx3cE4ghPKYlb1UU-rzYM71AbXZWsc5padKIO26hI7mvgBa3eFVJ2As_i9l977Uk9nt35SJ3CY26zFC9qd-Qn1ef5m1sVKf6ff0QTNOJSw4z3RGN6M1wgPgJhSuG6n0ueIOj-HYXOioN45qbErGCjHFdSEQ\",
>   \"Nonce\": \"637279998148674012.ZjFkMzkwNGQtNjkwNC00Yzk2LWJhNzMtZGY1YzYwOTliNmIxMzk5Mzk0ZGYtODVjYi00ZDdkLWFmMjUtNGY1YzVhZmE5ODNk\",
>   \"PromptMode\": \"login\",
>   \"SessionId\": \"d60608bcfa4c4a863486ad98773c8a7d\",
>   \"Raw\": {
>     \"client_id\": \"Sitecore\",
>     \"response_mode\": \"form_post\",
>     \"response_type\": \"code id_token token\",
>     \"scope\": \"openid sitecore.profile\",
>     \"state\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=zYO-qtV_MLTRvsaL8md9EXlT0L0-ljoenKICj2aJYW2fXwvg4bms9-Fa9JlNx3cE4ghPKYlb1UU-rzYM71AbXZWsc5padKIO26hI7mvgBa3eFVJ2As_i9l977Uk9nt35SJ3CY26zFC9qd-Qn1ef5m1sVKf6ff0QTNOJSw4z3RGN6M1wgPgJhSuG6n0ueIOj-HYXOioN45qbErGCjHFdSEQ\",
>     \"nonce\": \"637279998148674012.ZjFkMzkwNGQtNjkwNC00Yzk2LWJhNzMtZGY1YzYwOTliNmIxMzk5Mzk0ZGYtODVjYi00ZDdkLWFmMjUtNGY1YzVhZmE5ODNk\",
>     \"redirect_uri\": \"https://<url>/identity/signin\",
>     \"sc_account_prefix\": \"sitecore\\\",
>     \"prompt\": \"login\",
>     \"sc_message\": \"**You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator**.\",
>     \"x-client-SKU\": \"ID_NET451\",
>     \"x-client-ver\": \"5.2.2.0\"
>   }
> }
> ```

Everything was working fine until we migrate the DB server. When we migrate the DB server, the error comes up. This issue happening only for specific peoples. Some of them able to login successfully.

Please let me know how to fix this

Comment: It looks like the AD account with which you are logging in is already created in Sitecore as a persistent user, Same can be verified from Sitecore User manager

Comment: please let me know how to resolve this incase if user already there, use that. If it is a new user, create one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, i just restarted the Identity server app service and everything started working fine.